# android Volley how to parse Json

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

android Volley how to parse Json  first node "usercard" signle time and "cards" multiple time Repeat as loop getter setter Object how to use ArrayList 
json Structure completed 
object Store data ArrayList ;

please Help me

```
    {
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "usercard": {
      "UsrID": "822",
      "UsrTitle": "Mr.",
      "UsrFNm": "RAI",
      "UsrMNm": "S",
      "UsrLNm": "Patil",
      "UsrPicture": "1686cd3e8c3336deb124ee4f0e514f44_t.jpg?1476251936",
      "UsrDsgntnNm": "Software Developer",
      "UsrCompID": "456",
      "UsrCompNm": "Miracle RAI Test",
      "UsrCompRoleDesc": "",
      "UsrBrID": "710",
      "UsrFun": "",
      "UsrCity": "1131447",
      "UsrCityNm": "Mumbai",
      "UsrState": "1618",
      "UsrStateNm": "Maharashtra",
      "UsrCty": "107",
      "UsrCtyNm": "India",
      "UsrBuy": "",
      "UsrSell": "",
      "UsrPriInd": "41",
      "UsrPriIndNm": "Digital & Technology",
      "UsrSecInd": "147",
      "UsrSecIndNm": "Digital Services",
      "UsrArtReadCnt": "0",
      "UsrArtWriteCnt": "0",
      "UsrDisReadCnt": "0",
      "UsrDisWriteCnt": "0",
      "UsrComWriteCnt": "0",
      "UsrDisResCnt": "0",
      "UsrJoinDate": "",
      "UsrCompVerified": "0",
      "UsrProCompletion": "36",
      "UsrLinkCnt": "3",
      "UsrSts": "A",
      "UsrMobileSts": "1",
      "UsrEmailSts": "1",
      "UsrTyp": "2",
      "EntID": "9",
      "UsrAdrsLn1": "",
      "UsrAdrsLn2": "",
      "UsrAdrsLn3": "",
      "UsrAdrsPinCd": "",
      "UsrDegree": "2",
      "UsrFavorites": 0,
      "UsrLinkSts": "",
      "UsrLoginID": "s.",
      "UsrWebsite": "",
      "UsrCreatedDate": "2016-10-12 05:58:58",
      "UsrTwitter": "",
      "UsrBlog": "",
      "UsrSocialOther": "",
      "SMERole": "",
      "Source": "",
      "DOB": "",
      "UsrProfileComplected": "36"
    },
    "user_links": {
      "total_count": "3",
      "cards": [
        {
          "UsrID": "946",
          "UsrTitle": "Ms.",
          "UsrFNm": "mi",
          "UsrMNm": "p",
          "UsrLNm": "sawde",
          "UsrPicture": "rofile/MS.png",
          "UsrDsgntnNm": "Html Developer",
          "UsrCompID": "494",
          "UsrCompNm": "pqr",
          "UsrCompRoleDesc": "",
          "UsrBrID": "752",
          "UsrFun": "",
          "UsrCity": "1131447",
          "UsrCityNm": "Mumbai",
          "UsrState": "1618",
          "UsrStateNm": "Maharashtra",
          "UsrCty": "107",
          "UsrCtyNm": "India",
          "UsrBuy": "",
          "UsrSell": "",
          "UsrPriInd": "38",
          "UsrPriIndNm": "Computers, Peripherals & Applications",
          "UsrSecInd": "394",
          "UsrSecIndNm": "Software and Support Services",
          "UsrArtReadCnt": "0",
          "UsrArtWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisReadCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrComWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisResCnt": "0",
          "UsrJoinDate": "",
          "UsrCompVerified": "0",
          "UsrProCompletion": "33",
          "UsrLinkCnt": "1",
          "UsrSts": "A",
          "UsrMobileSts": "1",
          "UsrEmailSts": "1",
          "UsrTyp": "2",
          "EntID": "9",
          "UsrAdrsLn1": "",
          "UsrAdrsLn2": "",
          "UsrAdrsLn3": "",
          "UsrAdrsPinCd": "",
          "UsrDegree": "3",
          "UsrFavorites": 0,
          "UsrLinkSts": ""
        },
        {
          "UsrID": "445",
          "UsrTitle": "Mr.",
          "UsrFNm": "Somin",
          "UsrMNm": "",
          "UsrLNm": "Patil",
          "UsrPicture": "hprofile/SP.png",
          "UsrDsgntnNm": "Software Developer",
          "UsrCompID": "271",
          "UsrCompNm": "Miracle-ICICI Web Solutions Pvt. Ltd.",
          "UsrCompRoleDesc": "BizDev",
          "UsrBrID": "425",
          "UsrFun": "Administration",
          "UsrCity": "1131447",
          "UsrCityNm": "Mumbai",
          "UsrState": "1618",
          "UsrStateNm": "Maharashtra",
          "UsrCty": "107",
          "UsrCtyNm": "India",
          "UsrBuy": "",
          "UsrSell": "",
          "UsrPriInd": "41",
          "UsrPriIndNm": "Digital & Technology",
          "UsrSecInd": "147",
          "UsrSecIndNm": "Digital Services",
          "UsrArtReadCnt": "3",
          "UsrArtWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisReadCnt": "4",
          "UsrDisWriteCnt": "1",
          "UsrComWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisResCnt": "1",
          "UsrJoinDate": "2015-01-16 00:00:00",
          "UsrCompVerified": "2",
          "UsrProCompletion": "49",
          "UsrLinkCnt": "16",
          "UsrSts": "A",
          "UsrMobileSts": "2",
          "UsrEmailSts": "1",
          "UsrTyp": "2",
          "EntID": "8",
          "UsrAdrsLn1": "",
          "UsrAdrsLn2": "",
          "UsrAdrsLn3": "",
          "UsrAdrsPinCd": "",
          "UsrDegree": "1",
          "UsrFavorites": 0,
          "UsrLinkSts": "connected"
        },
        {
          "UsrID": "351",
          "UsrTitle": "Mr.",
          "UsrFNm": "Ysh",
          "UsrMNm": "s",
          "UsrLNm": "Yahoo",
          "UsrPicture": "c40bbd1e50addca687b6e75ae658f_t.jpg?1401777417",
          "UsrDsgntnNm": "Software Developer",
          "UsrCompID": "212",
          "UsrCompNm": "Technova",
          "UsrCompRoleDesc": "",
          "UsrBrID": "345",
          "UsrFun": "",
          "UsrCity": "1131447",
          "UsrCityNm": "Mumbai",
          "UsrState": "1618",
          "UsrStateNm": "Maharashtra",
          "UsrCty": "107",
          "UsrCtyNm": "India",
          "UsrBuy": "282",
          "UsrSell": "345,367,368",
          "UsrPriInd": "31",
          "UsrPriIndNm": "Automotives, Automobiles & Vehicles",
          "UsrSecInd": "391",
          "UsrSecIndNm": "Automobile Parts Manufacturer",
          "UsrArtReadCnt": "4",
          "UsrArtWriteCnt": "1",
          "UsrDisReadCnt": "8",
          "UsrDisWriteCnt": "2",
          "UsrComWriteCnt": "0",
          "UsrDisResCnt": "2",
          "UsrJoinDate": "",
          "UsrCompVerified": "0",
          "UsrProCompletion": "53",
          "UsrLinkCnt": "8",
          "UsrSts": "A",
          "UsrMobileSts": "2",
          "UsrEmailSts": "1",
          "UsrTyp": "2",
          "EntID": "7",
          "UsrAdrsLn1": "Hallmark plaza",
          "UsrAdrsLn2": "Nr. MIG colony",
          "UsrAdrsLn3": "",
          "UsrAdrsPinCd": "400051",
          "UsrDegree": "2",
          "UsrFavorites": 0,
          "UsrLinkSts": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get and parse a JSON-object with Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927754/how-to-get-and-parse-a-json-object-with-volley)

Comment: Use Gson library to parse the data.See this link for the reference https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: This will help http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/