# open https connection (distance matrix api)

Tags: https, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to use google distance matrix api

I'm using this url through volley request, and i get a `VolleyError (onErrorResponse)`:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+pickup+"&destinations="+destination+"&key=API-KEY
```

I have tried to open the url using an intent like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

but I get this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
Intent { 
    act=android.intent.action.VIEW
    dat=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
        origins=Hai Si Redouane, Oran
        &destinations=Place Premier November 1954, Oran, Algeria
        &key=API-KEY 
}
```

Notice: I am using a real device and url is working fine when I open it from browser

Comment: I do remember commenting on the same question from you. The url you are trying to access doesn't return HTML content but instead returns JSON data. Try to solve it in that manner

Comment: yes i have done that with volley and i get get a VolleyError ... the problem is that the url does not open at all from the app but it opens normally from the browser ... also.. i'm using google directions web api and it's working fine ... so the problem is just with distance matrix .

Comment: Browsers these days are capable to show the JSON data but still that doesn't make it a webpage to access

Comment: Take a look at this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927754/how-to-get-and-parse-a-json-object-with-volley . It addresses the same problem you are facing