# Json parsing data set into Layout android

Tags: android, json

i have use Volley for json parsing in android. and get the google Api data from bellow API. How can i set the data get from the `response` in try block to set into Card Layout of ListView?  What should i write in try block?

`private String urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.2150756,72.8880545&radius=500&type='+data+'&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";`

`makeJsonObjectRequest()` function as bellow,

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
showpDialog();

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


        try {
            JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("results");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        hidepDialog();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // hide the progress dialog
        hidepDialog();
    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

i want to set the json object data for the list of the cardview as bellow layout,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.chaitanya.nearbyplace.ItemDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image_bg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vicinity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textColor="#666"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I got the response from above google API as bellow, I want to set name, vicinity, lat and long of location into layout.

```
    {
html_attributions: [ ],
next_page_token: "CpQCBQEAAKeuGrGmIh_jyjPfFCrCTrwAJQhuVHb057iK85VIb8yNPsl1lNGhgw9B1-MNssPxqxgzuHC5g8ouZ9q45YdBq_KploWXHkC6MMLZtHdQVLtkmtmXi_CK0xa2a2kopFldOr1g5ok7uV__CwfJi5E-PuzQLnaERDInDhuuQ2WdGLXgYj_D_KB2N0m4ZgFNXNwmm2JQZUhl88dn94Gkjdk30jsbzV4A78BfaU9AUh6JxGhybMT4iJPe2O_GRZkr2I8nzTKVLxEo6fafhZIKmZF1pef_-xm7W3FwV9d2PZs2u5VOWpngwuuUpC7zyS18LKAmfcUc9dVpaPyvdNKsfh7fW94gaO7a_arjbEbCpciOB8FQEhAeDWAji1f7ULOP9hgdI_vCGhRfIWZ_uxsQBX16vD4MKrRscFcZvQ",
results: [
{
geometry: {},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
id: "7cd150c5220b034754a061ade85f7925cd350f2c",
name: "Surat",
photos: [],
place_id: "ChIJYxUdQVlO4DsRQrA4CSlYRf4",
reference: "CmRbAAAAHL2_fDcOhVKfx9yYc-lJgl-O7ArACJ6ccxl4ZaIbbUXovcEOAqDa9D1S4L3NedX2iaNUlZ_LZsTT7awsBExGFfkVQlA7VSHr5lPE-NpXpcOPduZY1EdJ2kg2myQ8uJUUEhBYZNOPzkNMEzufeE8i-QfOGhQ7FisrEv9jZbVYp5k1suyKwKQqog",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"locality",
"political"
],
vicinity: "Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2152405,
lng: 72.8883663
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2166047802915,
lng: 72.8897690302915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2139068197085,
lng: 72.88707106970848
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "c4672573fd8c42ab9c7454eb84da65e14c8f7c6b",
name: "Angel Broking Ltd. in Varachha, Gujarat",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 1152,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111670797900783602226/photos">Angel Broking Ltd. in Varachha, Gujarat</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAGaW6wrGq6r4gqebxVOlvTbl_epIUPSpdHHR8kzkSbHHXRaqKf-CaBsy2soYrpvc6prWlTc1NV_I4V0SPx2bknW00bnAeprskMvBRYAPkZhohLacMGF0CdYgo_PF_SK_U9TYgba_EhN7mtHttpfjdH24pIMPSkuSPs8DIMjIJF-MEhAAP79bCGXpCiMmClqxUBJ_GhSId-vUDZFlqYH3hfHhicx8fC5RMg",
width: 2048
}
],
place_id: "ChIJX0F0GlFO4DsRiTZ1oCVeOPw",
rating: 4.9,
reference: "CmRSAAAAmveyUh_jZu2DY9WazYB3PmxIEX6Jxr47W-naDv42Tcjg0F6GbK39Os7edGR7O2wA94V5SCOI1n7VdhKr7BXeCkYLneSNaI75NV1eEp2Gu1xN3Ghsw08l1s1GEHgYaCV4EhBq_Yg9M43owyfoau62rpiqGhQwpjJ0E9SUs54yQr6zSVWzZS2ecw",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"finance",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "shop No 2 First floor Swastik Plaza Yogi chowk ground Nana Varachha, Varachha, Yogi Chowk, Yogi Chowk Ground, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2162,
lng: 72.8883
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2175489802915,
lng: 72.88964898029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2148510197085,
lng: 72.8869510197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
id: "a4d8d75c5c4c5e8aa3972221c9406ab3d3c11999",
name: "Vari Filters",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJQTgcv3pP4DsREa_DKVP-oQc",
rating: 4.5,
reference: "CmRRAAAAn4hp9ScUEqNcuej83DIN7Tb0l6LLGI7fHZ4VD3eMISqjMP38U7bcbleR1cskBAe0XIrQDFo1gRIK-TKI5VvsFU-xCXGVTI26YnIF6AwLIPaaHGtKj_NvnhHE4HqOcUrhEhD1H1b8qMhfw9bSOyCr1bIKGhSoeccLRq6i8ur7CjxTPW3TInoziA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"home_goods_store",
"store",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "28, Yogiraj Shopping Centre,Puna-Shimada Road, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.213663,
lng: 72.885807
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2150119802915,
lng: 72.88715598029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2123140197085,
lng: 72.8844580197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "4e9519cf1a521e002138e95173e29d4e65522bde",
name: "Raksh Infotech",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 916,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102373953062335003973/photos">Raksh Infotech</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAANF0xC5aDw447-IyPbXiuy56e1svRhseazPc8CVwieBw3vw0MeCtZZ424Wb3cv9u3LaEgTUOOzm-4Q_s8XH9HDMNUEQJQxCrRJNf4nPd7PYz8maG4LQUnncnU2nqVHvIeTkzlEoxs4Y4stWu9apOjT_aNuVfMVHHH91eA4DwGWL_EhAX9C1eHz0zJhaYwnurVJSnGhTUFocaLjpViUGlWU4XtyoObTK3Pg",
width: 916
}
],
place_id: "ChIJZ5Lk33BP4DsRE8wz5WQHw2Y",
rating: 4.8,
reference: "CmRRAAAAM6E8Fb5UEE7uCUsv3m5GrbjEUckebjLIs1tArIiYyKKMg73NeCZZs0B_c1PSnpHGhQY9qptPxJshPx2sdccTx5xQRUh0IH8Tkg0Z0fgajIoDSgPxVjDFODsJFsiivLDQEhDgl4t4iv50cwPaASMohYFQGhRedEStUKPtNjGZ7rLYKrGCm9mhSw",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "4040,4th Floor, Palladium Mall, Yogi Chowk,Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.214714,
lng: 72.887856
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2160629802915,
lng: 72.88920498029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2133650197085,
lng: 72.8865070197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "de4b3dc1a403a2deb9586a98a6dce627defc03a0",
name: "Enjoy Technology",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 743,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115033077805993566369/photos">Enjoy Technology</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAKVG4uYY1wDanyViz9Cy5xBVOvPnAUN14lHzZqMLD_8nm6SEs-O7SX5YIrDDnvdsnhjBi6YTHJaZgBfe9-enuxfN5d-DbCKe9UNEOClWCIH4RGkFA1ySizncrYNuO8rxRmXC_CAcEnN5QaF6ut5nMRGTxmgrH466OMiDlPagVOY7EhAW5ONTs6yKJIZg5p4VQv0VGhQl3dHe_KXZclqfSfTtO2AooZNZhw",
width: 743
}
],
place_id: "ChIJSch6hAJP4DsRXxjp6dqeh50",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAdOvO4h3gTZtCIMXVCRX3pZ7_RPqigoEwMz8nnFXnrXPIq_7KxGKXAT33OkegfnwmmNyk4SQWNhC7Z3ei_zAacheBEz55NikqJdHAtH3Lmn4DQp7415fEEmy-tqsUpul_EhBITFM5kbgehWVk2KBk38JpGhTuRO2v4JK2UN6K44EsJwpd4_AMsg",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"electronics_store",
"home_goods_store",
"store",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "212, Apple square, Yogichowk, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.213988,
lng: 72.88686899999999
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2153369802915,
lng: 72.8882179802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2126390197085,
lng: 72.8855200197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "1f403c5c398ad14f76ac7ecea14f17855d7bee42",
name: "Sunbless Solar Energy",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 584,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108593742611026773915/photos">Sunbless Solar Energy</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAEhivyRKW-d9vmv2hALJWsFUmwefJZcBnYCm5Lhwcylhun0-E5OtwgVvZnv_qUYkG68tQBbnTCCsOUKgYxbnPQe5qwNtnjCnVAJaK_tF_0zxA8Lm_hmee4VOlOh79pT_Gg-5Z0n_NqbMDRCHyi1kTmxmuj5--0Th02k0HNtTxeF7EhAKHvYYPy1BAjLQ-FpQtEZjGhQo1x8kjdInjakHhwp4gR9B5by-ig",
width: 800
}
],
place_id: "ChIJAQAAAJxP4DsRMODaC6VfPuQ",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAA_kMAJ2w1Gf2GL4OS-lVnVniBcht8bq0uvS33rwwD0aAmIpk9tdGQx7Lb2WIfzMLFxBwvZBCkypaaSjgtGlVCWXlQrvcUpHj_6r9TiuY0XTkIzMN3fsM3Xx8RhbULE5k0EhCJd7TE_q5GS7N7tT5KICJsGhSt8B9pyMhBl4IY_lpxDUBRXLealA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"home_goods_store",
"store",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2148377,
lng: 72.8884345
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2161866802915,
lng: 72.88978348029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21348871970849,
lng: 72.88708551970849
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "8d2a10cb096e896686e9839de1898e0b1b770fd4",
name: "Krivi Infotech",
place_id: "ChIJgbRPi3pP4DsR2sEoqyvS6Lg",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAP6o3MP-5h8EoGOsnMFJlzfC_OszJyTJ2bW2IVLnTjMe0rK6tV-xJrPeTFk4INT56wviNm7EUMqNCVY7f7IGCwfunF5iTiI2qBByw3ckKMHZZzBbZh6Obr1_aNMiw0Aj_EhD0ObVh4X5BuDzmHj1lxW2JGhT_JUi_Mw7AxkngFO4WhTUSibuHXg",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.21503,
lng: 72.888188
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2163789802915,
lng: 72.88953698029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21368101970849,
lng: 72.8868390197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "3da36ddfa0800c5dadb8311bede7e780b48f5d46",
name: "WP INFOTECH",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJZYdFIWZP4DsRh-6sg1qX9sQ",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAzlQyEpHIKJyySQEEH4vgKv20T_PZxF6SJT84e2iXA5z1i7aycia7s7QBUBNoxim_3drWbnX3nKwvISeMUdbDIp8qXo1tuuDOOOdzSE1IjSGEqlbSsb0pCvJaq02ApNUxEhABvTAXNCiARHV3LWfJs5RDGhSGZG9yfd_2q_rLnwlpj83J9U3j1A",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "320, Swastik Plaza NR Yogi Chowk, Puna Simada Road, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2142,
lng: 72.88884999999999
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2155489802915,
lng: 72.8901989802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21285101970849,
lng: 72.88750101970848
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "9a6fcb8fa12ae3206ae590dda6b13e85841a61a2",
name: "Jay Khodiyar Tourist",
place_id: "ChIJTwD_W3pP4DsRJ8H7nZVi3Jo",
reference: "CmRSAAAAHU_jgu6rPhgMEdWfi-UVS3AWyouWQ_dFrKbASSVAeq-J9Z8WDcMFA-e7pkM7ef2E2-lP5K5cP1ZhgD_HUcJoLgIcvEMvBpyQsM54dJmnnTyIEg5JBSbUfPXSkZVIeKbdEhBA1G0Tqr5traxHnFTWnzFKGhRmQn-dY15Cg7a_COx2NVeshrfYjQ",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"travel_agency",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "40-shankarnagar Society, Over Bridge Road, Kapodra, Varachha Road, Kapodra, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.215091,
lng: 72.88806699999999
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2164399802915,
lng: 72.8894159802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21374201970849,
lng: 72.8867180197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "5c666a3e494401be23d291835d50fc9830a191ee",
name: "Hirani Developer",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 1200,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114506449742407435169/photos">Hirani Developer</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAOqp0YRiVzuRTKqP0HAREaztokBd9cy3745DI5aQ0bwUCzIqjf0WZCU57o66kWXVPBxYRHEufrmfq26itKZ8sj_T68Otmov76B7wUQBu4PllhukgQv0vqRA5RI8x2wcyMngGy2WE-96zxtkfrr8g9IL5qBFwY7OurHlWQN-cQ9onEhD4DPJy9fG0U-Rbqcl2LvQYGhT3KZC5lpSDatgwyTWY5bSviKA8qw",
width: 1920
}
],
place_id: "ChIJL1fNA6dP4DsREdkaoGl351w",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRRAAAAxB7vDaUZ3AngaYVOpdK-vR4iNVYNDTQB7FMViwyxnnCW7PzGBmliEEc11AlkMS_TvFWBcKnp82cpV3tPIY5DwQ239Wk0HEbAv0wjLyVw0CILmgXM3P7zZlMo4801jsviEhCV544wlJcEaIgQuNMS00K7GhRStGHIZaO9uuIwEi0tyjJrhrYIKA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Yogi Chowk, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2150799,
lng: 72.8880784
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.21642888029151,
lng: 72.8894273802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2137309197085,
lng: 72.88672941970849
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "523294afd5b7a88b7323e1c3301404e7c58d1e9d",
name: "Life Vision India",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJo1N3jnpP4DsRP842SGUCSUY",
reference: "CmRRAAAAuDqOzP5gLANoxJY_2JcAnNK7SFjFm8ysYSd_E2YpGyHGpx0iNNCvCn4M3OO0QK_-dJkBW9s0mmcUnBJUESpRJ-37Sv5GK1B90xdy99LkOKdzes51DL7FNr8ymCSNKyVmEhBMuteA7O7p_tO4EoNuoXCWGhSBppkdKHau6JNS9hokcd_CGnd_Gw",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"real_estate_agency",
"finance",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "11/12/13, Intercity Shopping Centre, 406, Puna Kumbhariya Road, Pravat Patiya, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2150798,
lng: 72.888088
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2164287802915,
lng: 72.88943698029149
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2137308197085,
lng: 72.88673901970849
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "e6b80f583222d4a3bfcafb5b0e37a5a616cd452a",
name: "3StarInfo",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJOQ2cjnpP4DsRjdblbeAWhug",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAAcyymj946GUle70ctyhkczFA2aJbHfSnOw7Pmp6d0RMjpicKstlQgi3ORQsh7A0ztW7CJ0rI9adyZO1UoWOnoy6m91CVQq5ojDfVIx8JIIzQCM7wXBdJYvUHFcE6O963EhB-ZcUJTXblgyxElv7al8epGhTQ_qTxDWeXB19eRnLQM_6yQP0CyA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "327- 3rd Floor, Swastik Plaza, Yogi Chowk, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.215105,
lng: 72.888072
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2164539802915,
lng: 72.8894209802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2137560197085,
lng: 72.88672301970848
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "ba22d4b733cd8971ece99efd0d11a84e539b0249",
name: "Bollymode",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 597,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102430645533875034276/photos">Bollymode</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAADiDNMFpRWvDcHKxVoo7CahdUBQ0kf2BNW1U9DIQi60ABqbVKh8iUaBZDBIP15W2w9paORFDAzpz1oYonGGW7MBfdUYke59bBRcWfzwVUhaXIqjfVLpuJScg1DBLnrFYHHe1ped78EgqMJORGih9daNmeGDNbWdP2jxvg4Xt3jTeEhAHlC8oS-5ftcvAcSr9BV4MGhSlAhSuFo_bCF5LoPmReUkOGtTCXg",
width: 1080
}
],
place_id: "ChIJj-pzjnpP4DsRCMVJwgKaAp0",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAWs7TYCG2ldxCTdN-P8N43CxLZML8nXWqRdvPaCeIYFXY4eqgFPtGYKiqj6_R5yV2KXO4BswFbJHI1g00B4oTsK9UPTBBLSJi5GgGnzh0du8u5abH8WlpyakUBvIDzq7CEhAX3QWC_xsWSwgnyXcZwfxGGhSvkipM9RzUHnM7uGjoudio4DzuIA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "S-28,Swastik Plaza,Yogi chowk,Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2150252,
lng: 72.8880959
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.21637418029151,
lng: 72.8894448802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2136762197085,
lng: 72.8867469197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "717ff06d5cd3e4bfd42cda26591cfdf80c9745f3",
name: "Patel Brothers And Company",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJlzaAjnpP4DsRR11YBvaoBWM",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRRAAAAdqbo1t8DE-Vvq2Qc04FniM1TScJKopzRhglitS6ru8VwTZVCGnRIyJcY5Ga60EvRmvgfN6SwBcOmGUvGfoNErFxTctURJT5Lj2d6urup6p0_BkEFJXIrSX3wBwXZBPG9EhCsgiZViOY6KB9jRbv9Lk4PGhShMSO7HhBMSFIJuie1yI474LEzqg",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"accounting",
"finance",
"lawyer",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Swastik Plaza, Varachha Rd, Yogi chowk, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.215091,
lng: 72.888149
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2164399802915,
lng: 72.88949798029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21374201970849,
lng: 72.8868000197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "3e53dfd58b8b6dbb3e31db6e14c0dbf0d1e2e6da",
name: "Tata Docomo Brand Store",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 720,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106018722847803093598/photos">Tata Docomo Brand Store</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAADqks_ARjMm1_QA33FaJs5Ilp8Mv7Ey5t2HcexWK1zcUKnLLgkN61W1VCAe5Yfr_tdYaUzO6IQDXLnT4CGJ0tShIf2NNzCQd0u7bJEVWed8a_moduv1eujw-YpFFfceZjVba2jRaAr1WOB_F6L26QV5s1VOe5GM6aP3FOQhcm1lwEhCo7iU1q7TwQubQUBpXqTZMGhRtkZ9LSqh5EX4aX--WRL0dnEsl3Q",
width: 720
}
],
place_id: "ChIJK0jFjXpP4DsRPSIkbmnQBvU",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAA5JolkSl8UklykTwF7Yg1X1ajY9ExInaSUIrbw8rhTCi7wlrPPdfMiWrh1JORUZM2QmHXNoR1WENv-mn4Os64vNM-jXeXZVIg5Lu76iCt36brDlGtsLVZkLP3XgCG3MqIEhBOYCCikmDfhQtyI21ForegGhRlYN4OuA-q4z6aIKlbx0hiM02KSQ",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Yogi Chowk, Shop no. G-17, Ground Floor, Swastik Plaza, Yogi Chowk, Puna Simana Road, Surat, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.215074,
lng: 72.8881502
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2164229802915,
lng: 72.88949918029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21372501970849,
lng: 72.8868012197085
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png",
id: "c4e94f696e12f14e0d96af68d74d4a68eb6229cb",
name: "Jan Suvidha Kendra",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 927,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112616388633727288615/photos">Jan Suvidha Kendra</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAOTfKifn8UocCsnRcLsjSjaPXblzDuneTwt-blEJv4rQ12T1zlEXVW5JF1swMNiknavD-lj8Ykzg5IqvmlSfoLZJ1d3wqEUnloDvVEa8HKAPLWU6v1PxBLpAEXHTKyHUm4zMKR_TTkAIIeHPzwHsIVIae15BjoAr3yzBtT6sZAUMEhBt_Sr441fJMpuORWXAVUw-GhTZNOTXN1oW6iPu5WJvmAB2bmvgJg",
width: 927
}
],
place_id: "ChIJ3TLOjXpP4DsRdAWKVZEc-og",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAcMFZ65v9iWdjvasdbcArjLa-ErC_e_xDcnvLTBpMDO_A8QbpgS2OABKRcN72fSCQhpwprLP5UHSKiSWmN7lxScO2JFhGGqO1EZIShs2NpPYPd3yzvft_mCu0KI3YqZoJEhAcOULmAmRfDu2ctXeC5jApGhSMvy9TPxwGrV0uFvJbmAx5WOE86w",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "F-33 Swastik Plaza, Puna-Simada Road, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2150049,
lng: 72.88799089999999
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2163538802915,
lng: 72.8893398802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21365591970849,
lng: 72.88664191970848
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "affa6583fd3f438f2dde36c671f56db907c7262c",
name: "S.D. Winger Group",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJ1xL0jnpP4DsR9Nv9gKnoz-w",
reference: "CmRSAAAAd0ywtO_kfcH8Gbgm6mSftOjT__PNvZFx8LYMr8iHiSOnyFMIW8ot_ar9xv3X8M0i-c1ROcFcoHnaMWyzzaJg2lLJtYIHRhBcGlV_MTiFLhoTTk52fg__ijkTrow-_jt5EhB2ptSb84VNAJrUqeOWno_EGhRbFRLMN6GU439XSY6s2BT5ho4WSA",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"finance",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "S-44, Swastik Plaza, Yogi Chowk, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2150758,
lng: 72.88815389999999
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2162197802915,
lng: 72.8896123802915
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.2135218197085,
lng: 72.88691441970849
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
id: "3248dca0a03bd3622413bc3756a14befffd81bee",
name: "home2shopping",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
photos: [
{
height: 1536,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100104812703241440091/photos">home2shopping</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAHEFmDvT18EE5gheM_i30rQKNrRGisa_74HC7i9jWacyPow_mw3dykq4IqPVwyGnPBKFqH8tBbBcuYGDSj5GIIOQtCFAH8wIGfV48PRBtDORjNUJ15xhdgvtAMeGEbVAifiyrYb_sVOhJ8XqqU6aaSlZKIVo3SjeYjI1VdYdAoe4EhDzkwVj1tqhkQbDw3jJf6yKGhStLDY-KZTx3vYzAyxmqn1h4KitOA",
width: 1540
}
],
place_id: "ChIJC7TPjXpP4DsRwXRrPRzrzJA",
rating: 5,
reference: "CmRSAAAAvP289TZ20sYaKxrA8NM8JCJiP9peFsZdQlQwh9BU5mhElAFOxrjyukHVpAOg2WyOLDUixOjab_RAnV7MNBhdvtBsv1EUalBWLns6ynbLTWR93AlqvaAVxqCZeK0G3cN3EhABtOROnMDakdH4r67-j30WGhRkVHWdX2BgoOugMpsu91gXLzr_cQ",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"shopping_mall",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Swastik Plaza, Puna-Simada Road, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.21497549999999,
lng: 72.8880523
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.2163244802915,
lng: 72.88940128029151
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.21362651970849,
lng: 72.88670331970849
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
id: "96802cd287c62b4d661b66c669532d46b3ec774b",
name: "Vison Art Photo World",
opening_hours: {
open_now: true,
weekday_text: [ ]
},
place_id: "ChIJgXuQjnpP4DsRgWjqGmM9EY8",
reference: "CmRSAAAA_o-vUQpJpizz8EVRnzyLICKD2UCUoWSaOge74qQkkgaQyjE7goudjIlWxfcBdWO3uHCEBhs242Pm3e0kWWWGEnGzI7dOIMKSmq9A1ID0r8V0jVzf_klamSggdl2A5HS3EhDrg07V_JxoXtFtDuSz9aEMGhRaAy3RW3kpWUmVSqxvOSpHNi7jvg",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Vijay Nagar 2, Nana Varachha, Surat"
},
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 21.2123389,
lng: 72.8895199
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 21.21888,
lng: 72.90218899999999
},
southwest: {
lat: 21.20085,
lng: 72.8809991
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
id: "d55f80e820f33be158b6ea4da5b49554f52b2f19",
name: "Yoginagar Society",
photos: [
{
height: 3120,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110728722607576466721/photos">Vinubhai Mistry</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAAJ0TW60hGffxhQkawpoXdCaS8x1_As7P3KL6Ne_kK3757r6Ob8j1ZtPESXnkpZFgjhHi2FpY4m4RPj6sfaVZXS_tCWE4DMayubVaVoL6tuYnv8auFOMNE4oaUxhtuyMGV-1wiMcopoeEe5BLX0p04Z9ckurClvd-VvlqfssocpiEhDDOBCy0XrYZAuozSsCkyV0GhRoUErvIu7FmikgZomq6Yx54tccQw",
width: 4160
}
],
place_id: "ChIJze1HhntP4DsRv7yeijdWYDI",
reference: "CmRbAAAAP7v7TvtuZC_qoGgeMYQSy8uqAj8157KbEKM1wlrw-bY7sMqjOtin2OXXtIYNI-VsFEHsJ2O55V5nCSUfLviKle3JzE67jL0OJ9TDMxtsu2TsGNWKCe0tY70mrtfb1eQBEhDh7w6aVMv5Jb4-gqYzO9r4GhThxJ02mVFu-1qknUEFUYIHD4oagw",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"sublocality_level_1",
"sublocality",
"political"
],
vicinity: "Yoginagar Society"
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```

Comment: please explain proper your issue.where you get problem??

Comment: you can use custom adapter to assign your data to xml  look this http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: Try my answer. hope it will help to get your desired result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927754/how-to-get-and-parse-a-json-object-with-volley see this answer its help you to solve your parsing problem

Comment: i suggest to use gson for parsing when you get large response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `name`, `vicinity`, `lat` and `lng` from `JSON`, try this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


    try {
        JSONArray resultArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

        // First result
        JSONObject result = resultArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String name = result.getString("name");
        String vicinity = result.getString("vicinity");

        JSONObject geometry = result.getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

        double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
        double lng = location.getDouble("lng");

        // Do something with this values



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    hidepDialog();
}
```

**To show data on ListView:**

1. Use `ArrayList` or `HashMap` to store results(`name, vicinity, lat, lng`) from `onResponse()`
2. Create a custom `adapter` class that will populate list result data
3. Set this `adapter` to `ListView`
4. use notifyDataSetChanged() to update `ListView`

**Here is a good Tutorial:**

[Android Custom ListView with Image and Text using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: How can i show data into `ListView` of `Relative Layout`?

Comment: You need a custom adapter class to populate list of data on ListView.

Comment: can you please send me the link if there is any tutorial or example to perform as you have mention.

Comment: I have updated my answer with mentioning tutorial link. check this

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

Using a tool like [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), assuming you know the resultant `json` format, you can generate a `Plain Old Java Object` class that represents the `json` String.

From there, armed with your POJO class, you can use a library like `gson` to automatically map the json to the pojo; using a code like this:

```
ResultPojoEntity pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ResultPojoEntity.class);
```

Finally, you can set to the views whatever attribute you need like this:

```
someViewElement.setText(pojo.getSomeValue());
```

I hope this helps and if you need further clarification, let me know.

Good luck!