# How to parse JSON data without define array in JSON in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am new in Android I am trying to develop an application which is used to validate ifsc code by entering code in edit text.

So in this project, I am using Razorpay JSON to fetch data but when I fetch data it shows in JSON format  not readable format.

How to convert JSON data in a readable format?

My code works fine when I am adding square bracket [] in JSON  but I can't edit JSON because it is third-party JSON.

Here is my code:

```
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data = "";
    String dataprart ;
    String singlePared = "";
    String datamanner = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        dataprart=ifsccode.getText().toString();
        String urls="https://ifsc.razorpay.com/"+dataprart;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
            url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data= data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
            for ( int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);

                singlePared =
                    "BRANCH  --- " + JO.get("BRANCH") + "\n"+"\n"+
                    "STATE   ---" + JO.get("STATE") + "\n"+"\n"+
                    "DISTRICT ---" + JO.get("DISTRICT") + "\n"+"\n"+
                    "ADDRESS  --- " + JO.get("ADDRESS") + "\n"+"\n"+
                    "CITY  ---" + JO.get("CITY") + "\n"+"\n"+
                    "BANK   ---" + JO.get("BANK") + "\n";

                    datamanner = datamanner +singlePared;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        IFSc_validate.ifsc.setText(datamanner);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clearly understand the question but Can't you just use another jsonarray to save the razorpay json (which is giving you difficulty)?

Comment: in JSON array is not declared how to fetch  data without arry in JSON check out my json  https://ifsc.razorpay.com/sbin0003400   square bracket not define.

Comment: i still don't understand clearly .. but by any chance i think you are missing jsonparser. Coz after i normally receive a string i  use jsonparser to conbvert it into jsonarray or jsonobject.

Comment: sir, I am getting result in JSON format how I get the result in a readable format...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the response is a JSONObject and not a JSONArray.

Try these changes

```
        JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(data);
        singlePared = //continue
```

Remove the for loop and the JSONArray declaration

---

Also you should consider using volley to get an JSONObject response it would make life easier.

[How to get and parse a JSON-object with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927754/how-to-get-and-parse-a-json-object-with-volley)